# Checking if an item exists as a folder using POSIX notation in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have a string which represents a File/Folder in a Folder in POSIX notation:

```
/Users/surfacedetail/Desktop/Temp/Test1
```

I want to check if the the Test1 exists AND is a Folder. The following tells is that it exists:

```
if exists my POSIX file myFileOrFolder then
    beep
end if
```

This works ok, but how to tell if it is a Folder or a File?

The problem is that this is part of a massive script, this is a better test, it uses system events, but it doesn't work. I think its something to do with how I am building the path string.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set myScriptFilePath to (path to me)
    set mySourceFolder to folder of myScriptFilePath
    set myFileAliasList to the entire contents of mySourceFolder

    set myPOSIXSourceFolder to URL of mySourceFolder
    set myPOSIXSourceFolder to characters 8 thru -1 of myPOSIXSourceFolder as string

    repeat with myFile in myFileAliasList
        set myFileName to name of myFile
        log "myFileName: " & myFileName

        if (myFileName ends with ".txt") then
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
            set myFolderName to first text item of myFileName
            set myFolderPath to myPOSIXSourceFolder & myFolderName as string
            log "myFolderPath: " & myFolderPath

            tell application "System Events"
                if not (exists folder myFolderPath) then
                    beep
                    display dialog "Could not find Folder for File: " & myFileName
                    return {}
                end if
            end tell

        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `System Events` without any type cast

```
set thePath to "/Users/surfacedetail/Desktop/Temp/Test1"

tell application "System Events"
    if exists folder thePath then
        beep
    end if      
end tell
```

Comment: This doesn't work and I can't paste in the code I tried, this aspect of Stack Overflow is crap

Comment: My bad, I forgot a closing quote after `System Events`. The code works.

Comment: I fixed this and it compiles but the example I have now posted doesn't work.

Comment: Actually you don't need `URL` and POSIX paths at all. And as you are dealing with the Finder you don't need `System Events` either.

Comment: As I said its part of a larger script that DOES need POSIX paths. The rest of the scripts assumes they are in POSIX notation, this part of the script prepares a list of POSIX Folder Paths for another part to use.

Comment: Also it doesn't work if there are spaces anywhere in the file/folder path! See separate question. Oh Well, Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! It was because I wasn't restoring the text delimiter, it needed this:

```
set mySaveASDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
```

change delimiters

```
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to mySaveASDelimiters
```